# Associative array with Record type in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, collections, oracle11g

```
DECLARE
    TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF bse_daily_price%ROWTYPE  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    emp_tab EmpTabTyp;
    type_info varchar2(400);

BEGIN

    SELECT * INTO emp_tab(100) FROM bse_daily_price WHERE SECURITY_CODE = 500350 and BUS_DATE='02-01-14';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(emp_tab(100)));
END;
```

Errors:

> ORA-06550: line 11, column 25:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TO_CHAR'
> ORA-06550: line 11, column 9:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 3):

`emp_tab(100)` can't be converted into a string using [to_char()](https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=to_char&book=SQLRF&library=en%2Fdatabase%2Foracle%2Foracle-database%2F19), which is for individual numbers and dates etc.

You will need to concatenate the values in the record, e.g.

```
dbms_output.put_line
( emp_tab(100).firstname || ' ' || emp_tab(100).lastname );
```